# ¿Cómo usar varios HAVING con rango de precio?

Tags: mysql

tengo el siguiente problema, como puedo agrupar varios productos con dos rangos de precios en mysql, tengo estas  2 opciones pero ninguna me funciona

```
SELECT * 
FROM PRODUCTOS 
WHERE (producto_precio >=100 AND producto_precio <= 250) 
AND( producto_precio >=600 AND producto_precio <= 700)

SELECT * 
FROM PRODUCTOS 
HAVING (producto_precio >=100 AND producto_precio <= 250) 
AND( producto_precio >=600 AND producto_precio <= 700)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero, si no hay un group by, la clausula having no tiene sentido. Con el where alcanza...

Luego, tu where hace lo siguiente

```
(producto_precio >=100 AND producto_precio <= 250) 
AND
( producto_precio >=600 AND producto_precio <= 700)
```

Si lo leemos dice lo siguiente...

precio mayor a 100 y precio menor a 250 y precio mayor a 600 y precio menor a 700...

Pero SQL funciona fila a fila, con lo cual, eso que escribiste es imposible que suceda.

si vos queres los rangos, entre las dos condiciones tiene que haber un `OR`, para que quede:

precio mayor a 100 y precio menor a 250 O precio mayor a 600 y precio menor a 700...

```
(producto_precio >=100 AND producto_precio <= 250) 
OR
( producto_precio >=600 AND producto_precio <= 700)
```

Comment: no es mejor con between?

Comment: between es sugar y todo motor de sql lo expande a esto mismo. @FranciscoNúñez.. por lo cual, es lo mismo...

Comment: pero se ve mas bonito y simple con between....

Comment: ademas consultas extensas de rango o varios rangos pueden confundir al OP.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `BETWEEN` en tu clausula `WERE`, quedaría así:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS
WHERE
    (
        producto_precio BETWEEN 100 AND 250 /*primer Rango*/
    ) OR (
        producto_precio BETWEEN 600 AND 700 /*segundo Rango*/
    );
```

que es `BETWEEN` en Mysql?, aquí esta la documentación:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Que hace mejor a `BETWEEN` que otros operadores:

1. Puedes agregarle el `NOT` delante para hacer exclusiones de rango:

```
    SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS
    WHERE
        (
            producto_precio NOT BETWEEN 100 AND 250 /*primer Rango*/
        ) OR (
            producto_precio NOT BETWEEN 600 AND 700 /*segundo Rango*/
        );
```

2. El Mantenimiento es mucho más sencillo y mucho más legible.